# Get current date in the server-side of Nextjs 13

Tags: datetime, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I am working on a Nextjs 13 app with app router where I need to add current year to meta title.

currently I'm passing the year as slug into my page component and then setting the metadata with the year value.

```
my-page/[year]/page.tsx

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { year},
}: {
  params: { year: string };
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  return {
    title: `this is a sample title ${year}`,
    description: `this is a sample description`
    }
  };
}
```

Is there any other way to get the current year on server side?

I've tried this slug passing approach but here, I need to pass the year through the url. I'm looking for such a way where the year passing wont be necessary to get the year value in the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> *Is there any other way to get the current year on server side?*

**Solution :**

> *Use Date() Object or a Moment library*

**Using Date() Object :**

```
new Date().getFullYear() //2024
```

In your title key replace  :

> `${year}`

to

> `${new Date().getFullYear()}`

---

**Using Moment Library (*Installation needed*) :**

*(Why ? Its an library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates. provides many functions)*

**Install Moment Library :** `npm install moment`

```
// Import ES5 syntax :
var moment = require('moment'); // require

 // OR

// Import ES6 syntax :
import moment from 'moment';
```

In your title key replace  :

> `${year}`

to

> `${moment().year()}`

**Please Read :**

1. **Using Moment :** https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/
2. **moment().year() :** https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/
3. **Date :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
4. **getFullYear() :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: thanks man.. IDK why I dint try this Date() in my server side component earlier..